# Java SWT DND for multiple transfer types

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Java SWT DND for multiple transfer types: irrespective of TreeModel item first transfer type dnd works.Please find below code. "Type1" object DND works fine for below code.
First transfer type will work, If I change the order.
Please guide how to make other transfer types to work with out changing order?

```
    int ops = DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE;
    Transfer[] transfers = new Transfer[] { Type1.getInstance(), Type2.getInstance(), Type3.getInstance() };

    mydrop = new MyDropListener(treeViewer);
    mydrag= new MyDragListener(treeViewer);
    treeViewer.addDragSupport(ops, transfers, mydrag);
    treeViewer.addDropSupport(ops, transfers, mydrop);
```

/* Below is myDragListner */

```
public class MyDragListener extends DragSourceAdapter {

private final ISelectionProvider selectionProvider;

public MyDragListener(ISelectionProvider selectionProvider) {
    this.selectionProvider = selectionProvider;
}

 @Override
 public void dragFinished(DragSourceEvent event) {
         System.out.println("Finshed Drag");
 }

@Override
public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) selectionProvider
            .getSelection();

    TreeModel selectedDomainObject = (TreeModel) selection.getFirstElement();

    if (Item.getType(selectedDomainObject) == Item.T1)
    {
        Type1 t1 = (Type1) selectedDomainObject;
        event.data=t1;

    }

    if (Item.getType(selectedDomainObject) == Item.t2)
    {
        Type2 t2 = (Type2) selectedDomainObject;
        event.data=t2;
    }

}

 @Override
 public void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event) {
         System.out.println("Start Drag");
 }
```

}

/* Below is my drop listner  */

```
public class MyDropListener extends ViewerDropAdapter
{

public MyDropListener(Viewer viewer)
{
    super(viewer);
}


@Override
public boolean performDrop(Object data)
{

    TreeModel target = (TreeModel) getCurrentTarget();
    if (target == null)
        target = (TreeModel) getViewer().getInput();

    Mysession session = new Mysession();

    if (Item.getType(data) == Item.t1)
    {
        Type1 ty1= (Type1) data;
        session.addItem(ty1, target);
    }

    if (Item.getType(data) == Item.t2)
    {
        Type2 ty2= (Type2) data;
        session.addItem(ty2, target);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean validateDrop(Object target, int operation, TransferData transferType)
{
    return true;

}
```

Comment: This should work, the problem is probably in your drag/drop listeners - show us the source of those.

Comment: Please find the above added code.

Comment: @greg-449 Could you please tell where I am missing in above code!!!

Comment: There still isn't enough code to know, from the look of it there may be a problem in the Transfer classes or something like that.

Comment: Similar post is on Eclipse https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=137169&goto=432812&#msg_432812  I could not figure it out where problem is.  I have lengthy code which is difficult to post.